# How to pass data in ui-router through external redirects?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redirect

How can I pass data to my angular project using external redirects? 
I need to pass mdToast messages to my project from an external source. I need to intercept these messages at all the controllers. Currently, I am using query strings to achieve this right now. How can I intercept this query string in the runBlock? I want to somehow intercept it at all routes.

Here's how I am sending the query string:

```
$stateProvider
.state('toastIntercept', {
   url: '/toastIntercept?message',
   templateUrl: 'views/redirect-by-intercept.html',
   controller: 'redirectController'
 });
```

---

On further note, here's what I am actually trying to do:

**I understand discussions are discouraged here but I'd really appreciate some inputs or some resources or articles on this. I haven't been able to find any credible ones.**

I generate emails to my users using node. Users can take some actions through that email but ultimately land on my static angular project. What would be the right way to achieve this?

I can think of two possible ways:

1. Using a Proxy that handles the email redirection, performs the actions and redirects to the angular project using a toast message as a query string to notify the user about his action.
2. Instead of the Proxy, handle the email redirects on my static angular project itself using one of the routes. This however feels like an anti-pattern to me since a static project shouldn't be handling API level tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you could solve this problem by adding an interceptor.

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    //Register the interceptor via an anonymous factory    
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
          return {
           'request': function(config) {
               // same as above
            },

            'response': function(response) {
               // same as above
            }
          };
        });    
});
```

Yo could add interceptos for both requests and reponses. 
Other possible values for the interceptos are: 'requestError' and 'responseError'

You could Also define a factory and then do the following

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('connectionFactoryInterceptor');
```

Comment: Could you add the details from the webpage. Should the link ever go stale, the answer would lose its value. Thanks.